# Zend framework 2 routing error while click on link

Tags: zend-framework

A 404 error occurred
Page not found.

The requested controller could not be mapped to an existing controller class.

Controller:
    index(resolves to invalid controller class or alias: index)

No Exception available

Comment: Can you post the relevant route configuration?

Comment: sir i try to redirect page to other location which is allow by ACL in ZF2 but it not works.. and produce above error..

Comment: make sure your routing configuration points to the right controller and action; as @webjawns.com said please update your question.

Comment: [HTTP 404 error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404)